# How to create multiple url for single grails web application with dynamic DB switching

Tags: sql, angularjs, oracle, grails

Idea is to create multiple URL reference for a web application for each customer . (separate DB for each URL ) . 
This is to create a application to various user with one solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Idea is to create multiple URL reference for a web application for
>   each customer . (separate DB for each URL ) . This is to create a
>   application to various user with one solution.

GORM has support for multitenancy and one of the options is to use a subdomain resolver so `tenant1.yourapp.com` can have a different database than `tenant2.yourapp.com` even if those are both the same instance of the app.  More information is available at http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#multiTenancy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the endpoint for API calls is not the Domain... it is the Controller. Even when you create bindings to the domain for a RESTFUL API, a controller is still dynamically maintained/created to be able to deal with the MAPPINGS for the annotations.

This doesn't solve for an RPC API solution and is only limited to a CRUD-based RESTFUL API.